# Modification to allow a two dimensional array NxN to rotate 180 degrees instead of just 90 degrees?

Tags: c#

The method allows for rotation of 90 degrees, what kind of modification would allow it to rotate 180 degrees.

method:

```
public static int[,] RotateMatrix(int[,] matrix, int n)
    {
        int[,] ret = new int[n, n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                ret[i, j] = matrix[n - j - 1, i];
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried something by yourself? It seems to be very easy, you just need to think to it a couple of minutes to find a solution. See [ask].

Comment: Think about wha how the elements in the original map to the result. You've already done 90 degrees (which is harder), so you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

First thing - you can just run your code twice in order to achieve rotation by 180.
Another option is to use this method:

```
public static int[,] RotateMatrix(int[,] matrix, int n)
    {
        int[,] ret = new int[n, n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
            {
                ret[j, n - i - 1] = matrix[n - j - 1, i];
            }
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

I used your method and only modified the index of the **ret** matrix.

Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

```
ret[i, j] = matrix[n - 1 - i, n - 1 - j];
```

Your method should check `matrix.GetLength(0)` and `matrix.GetLength(1)`. Both should be at least `n`. If you want to use the method only when both agree, and then rotate the entire `n`×`n` matrix, you can leave out the `n` parameter and make `n` a local variable.

You can also define `m = matrix.GetLength(0);` and `n = matrix.GetLength(1);` and rotate possibly nonsquare matrices.

And you can make the method generic, `public static TElement[,] RotateMatrix<TElement>(TElement[,] matrix) { ... }`.